# how to pass function argument to call a function within an other module?

Tags: python

I need to use the arg to call an other function inside another module

Thank you!

```
def func (arg):
   if module.session.query(module.arg).filter(module.arg.id == id).one():
   #some other staff
```

Comment: you should use the [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function

Answer (score 0):

use the [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) built-in function:

```
def func (arg):
    if module.session.query(getattr(module, arg)).filter(getattr(module, arg).id == id).one():
```